# Is it possible to use a .dockerignore conditionally?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to use a `.dockerignore` file conditionally?

I have a huge C# codebase, and I obviously have a lot of tests.

But tests contain lots of miscelanious data (`~100-150mb` for all the tests in the whole codebase).

I would like to build an image only for testing and on an other image, just take what matters (`- tests`, `- other miscleanious stuff`)

Or should this be the case where I need to create a build script just for my use case?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#buildkit) as your builder backend, then [you can define a dockerignore specific to a certain Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#use-a-dockerignore-file):

> When using the BuildKit backend, docker build searches for a .dockerignore file relative to the Dockerfile name. For example, running docker build -f myapp.Dockerfile . will first look for an ignore file named myapp.Dockerfile.dockerignore. If such a file is not found, the .dockerignore file is used if present. Using a Dockerfile based .dockerignore is useful if a project contains multiple Dockerfiles that expect to ignore different sets of files.

So by enabling BuildKit (by setting the variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`), you can have a `testing.Dockerfile` with its own `testing.Dockerfile.dockerignore`.

Answer (score 0):

Docker ignore files have the same syntax as git ignore files.

This means you can use globs and negations to ignore, but otherwise *include* different sections on the file tree

You should not be bundling your application test resources into your final application image, however, so sounds like you need a multi-stage docker image or other test and build scripts that contain your conditions